# Selenium test triggers second instance of Firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium

I'm on a Mac using FF 33.1. The test suite, among other gems, uses Selenium, Capybara, and VCR. For some reason the tests trigger a second instance of Firefox (which I believe is causing most of the tests to fail):

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
```

What's causing the second instance and what can I do about it? I have updated the selenium-webdriver gem and done a bundle install.

Here is an example file that triggers the behavior:

```
require "spec_helper"

  describe 'Managing Sections' do
    use_vcr_cassette

    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      @organization = FactoryGirl.create :organization
      @membership = FactoryGirl.create :membership, :organization => @organization, :user => @user, :role => 'admin'
      @bulletin = Bulletin.create(organization: @organization, user: @user, title: 'Test Title', created: true, publish_date: '2013-5-12')
      login_user @user
      visit manage_organization_bulletin_sections_path(@organization, @bulletin)
    end

    it 'creates a organization section for mtb', js: true do
      @organization.sections.count.should eq 0
      @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 4
      click_link 'multi-button'
      fill_in 'Title', with: 'New MTB'
      fill_in 'Description', with: 'New MTB Desc'
      click_button 'Save'
      @organization.sections.count.should eq 1
      @bulletin.reload
      @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 5
    end


    it 'creates a organization section for stb', js: true do
      @organization.sections.count.should eq 0
      @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 4
      click_link 'single-button'
      fill_in 'Title', with: 'New STB'
      fill_in 'Description', with: 'New STB Desc'
      click_button 'Save'
      @organization.sections.count.should eq 1
      @bulletin.reload
      @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 5
    end



it 'creates a organization section for bis', js: true do
  @organization.sections.count.should eq 0
  @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 4
  click_link 'insert-button'
  fill_in 'Title', with: 'New BIS'
  fill_in 'Description', with: 'New BIS Desc'
  click_button 'Save'
  @organization.sections.count.should eq 1
  @bulletin.reload
  @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 5
end


it 'creates a organization section for cal', js: true do
  @organization.sections.count.should eq 0
  @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 4
  click_link 'calendar-button'
  fill_in 'Title', with: 'New CAL'
  fill_in 'Description', with: 'New CAL Desc'
  click_button 'Save'
  @organization.sections.count.should eq 1
  @bulletin.reload
  @bulletin.included_sections.count.should eq 5
end


describe 'Deleting MTBS' do
  before do
    visit manage_organization_bulletin_sections_path(@organization, @bulletin)
    click_link 'multi-button'
    fill_in 'Title', with: 'New MTB'
    fill_in 'Description', with: 'New MTB Desc'
    click_button 'Save'
    @bulletin.reload
    @organization.reload
  end

  it 'doesnt delete org mtb when more than one clone present', js: true do
    pending
    visit manage_organization_bulletin_sections_path(@organization, @bulletin)
    click_link 'multi-button'
    fill_in 'Title', with: 'New MTB2'
    fill_in 'Description', with: 'New MTB2 Desc'
    click_button 'Save'
    @bulletin.reload
    @organization.reload
    visit manage_organization_bulletin_sections_path(@organization, @bulletin)
    within '#multi_text_block_' + @bulletin.included_sections.last._id.to_s do
      click_link 'delete_section'
      page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
    end
    @bulletin.reload
    @organization.reload.sections.count.should eq 1
    visit manage_organization_bulletin_sections_path(@organization, @bulletin)
    within '#multi_text_block_' + @bulletin.included_sections.last._id.to_s do
      click_link 'delete_section'
      page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
    end
    @organization.reload.sections.count.should eq 0
  end

  it 'deletes org mtb when one clone present'
end


it 'doesnt delete org stb when more than one clone present'
it 'deletes org stb when one clone present'
it 'doesnt delete org bis when more than one clone present'
it 'deletes org bis when one clone present'
it 'doesnt delete org cal when more than one clone present'
it 'deletes org cal when one clone present'
```

end

Comment: How can we tell without seeing your codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe version 32-34 of Firefox cause this problem with the gem set you're using.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7642

Comment: Downgraded to FF 31 and it works... However, it still triggers a separate instance of FF???